# How do I save/update/pull information for an array inside of an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having issues finding out how I'm supposed to save an array inside of an array using mongoose. This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{
    "Server": "n/a",
    "Events": {
        {
            "EventName": "n/a",
            "EventType": "n/a",
            "EventTime": "n/a"
        },
        {
            "EventName": "n/a",
            "EventType": "n/a",
            "EventTime": "n/a"
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any ideas on how I could write/read data using mongoose on this type of table, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it - I realised it wasn't as complicated as I thought.
You just have to save it in an array, like this:
`{ EventNamme: "a", EventType: "b", EventTime: "c" }`

I declared that as a variable, and then pushed it through Model.Events.